# How to add navigation list on actionbar of ViewPage that is visible only on certain fragment?

Tags: android, navigation, android-actionbar, android-viewpager, spinner

I've a **ViewPager** with 3 Fragments.  I'm able to set the actionbar menu option selectively only for the fragment that I want.

Similarly I want to provide a *Navigation List via Spinner in the ActionBar*.  Here again, the Navigation List should appear only for the one of the fragment of the ViewPager and not for all the fragment.  However my attempt at this has failed.  The Navigation List appears in the actionbar but remains there for all the fragments.

Below is one of the fragments that I use in my ViewPager. I want the Navigation List to appear only when I slide this fragment in view.

```
public class TransactionsFragment extends SherlockFragment implements
    ActionBar.OnNavigationListener{

    private ActionBar mActionBar;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_transactions, container, false);

        // Set up the action bar to show a dropdown list
        mActionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

        final String[] dropdownValues = {"Test","Old"};

     // Specify a SpinnerAdapter to populate the dropdown list

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = null;
        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mActionBar.getThemedContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, android.R.id.text1,
                    dropdownValues);
        } else {
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, android.R.id.text1,
                    dropdownValues);
        }

        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // Set up the dropdown list navigation in the action bar.
        mActionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, this);

        return rootView;
    }
```

How can I restrict the Navigation List to appear only when this fragment is visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Fragment#setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#setUserVisibleHint%28boolean%29) will be triggerd when the fragment becomes visible/invisible.

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        // enable action bar list navigation
    } else {
        // disable action bar list navigation
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had same need as OP, and used the method suggested by Matthias, along with bits from other sources. For me, as a newcomer to Android, this was a challenge. I'm going to provide more detail, which may be helpful to others that arrive here via search.

All code for this is in the one Fragment that displays the navigation spinner. No mess in the other fragment(s).

```
private ActionBar actionBar;


public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if(actionBar==null) {

        actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();

        // get spinner items defined in values/strings/dropdown
        final String[] dropdownValues = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.dropdown);

        // set up the actionbar appearance
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

        // Specify a SpinnerAdapter to populate the dropdown list.
        ArrayAdapter<String> aAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(actionBar.getThemedContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, android.R.id.text1,dropdownValues);

        aAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // setup for callbacks to detect item selection
        actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(aAdapter, this);
    }
}

 @Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {

    //System.err.println("Spinner selection: " + itemPosition);
    //do stuff based on itemPosition

    return false;
}
```

And, finally, more complete code for turning the navigation spinner on and off:

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

    if (actionBar!=null) {
        if (isVisibleToUser) {
            actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
        }
        else  {
            actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Also, the Fragment must implement ActionBar.OnNavigationListener, like this...

```
public class DisplayStuffFragment extends Fragment implements ActionBar.OnNavigationListener {

...
}
```